# What is += operator doing in the provided C# code?

Tags: c#

What does this `+=` operator means in this code, is it a lambda? 
I read the MSDN document for the lambda but didn't find any thing about this `+=` operator, I will be thankful if someone explain it to me

```c#
translateButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    translatedNumber = Core.PhonewordTranslator.ToNumber(phoneNumberText.Text);
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(translatedNumber))
    {
        callButton.Text = "Call";
        callButton.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        callButton.Text = "Call " + translatedNumber;
        callButton.Enabled = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Click is an event, (list of delegates) and you're adding a new one. The `+=`  For example  `x += 2 ` equals `x = x + 2`

Comment: This is not related to `Xamarin`. This is just the way `C#` works.

Comment: @VSG24 this is a xamarin.android code

Comment: `xamarin.android` is not a language.

Comment: yeah you are right , removed xamarin tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an arithmetic operation `+=/-=` mean

> add/subtract the right side to/from the left side and assign the result to the left side.

So writing `a += 5` is the same as writing `a = a + 5`.

This code, however, is about events and event handlers. In the context of event handlers, `+=/-=` mean

> add/remove the following delegate to/from the list of event handlers for this event.

So your sample code adds a new event handler to the button's `Click` event. The way it is written is called inline implementation.

Please note that in the context of event handlers, you can usually **not** replace

```
Event += Handler;
```

by

```
Event = Event + Handler;
```

as there is no way to "read" the `Event` "property" outside the implementing class.

Answer (score 6):

`+=` adds an event handler to the `Click` event of `translateButton` object. See also this article at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx .

Answer (score 1):

In order to subscribe a method (Anonymous or named) to that event you use this syntax:

```
translateButton.Click +=  (object sender, EventArgs e) => { /* .. Code*/ }
```

Or

```
translateButton.Click += SomeMethodThatMatchesSignature;

private void SomeMethodThatMatchesSignature(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // .. Code
}
```

Note that if you `+=` two methods, both are going to be executed. You can remove one by use `-=` syntax.

> In the .NET Framework class library, events are based on the
>   EventHandler delegate and the EventArgs base class.
>
> Delegates with more than one method in their invocation list derive
>   from MulticastDelegate. Multicast delegates are used extensively in
>   event handling

Read More About Delegates [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx).

**Side-Note:** This is not by any mean specific to Xamarin!

Answer (score 1):

`+=` Add AND assignment operator, It adds right operand to the left operand and assign the result to left operand.

In your case you are assigning an delegate to handle your event. but Events aren't delegate instances.

The add and remove methods are called in C# using `eventName += delegateInstance;` and `eventName -= delegateInstance;` respectively, where eventName may be qualified with a reference (e.g. myForm.Click) or a type name (e.g. MyClass.SomeEvent).

In simple terms you are adding an event with the button. So `TranslateButton = TranslateButton + Event` will become `TranslateButton += Event`

Answer (score 0):

With += you add an event handler to the event.

The code that you showed could also be written like this:

```
    translateButton.Click += translateButton_Click;

    private void translateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        translatedNumber = Core.PhonewordTranslator.ToNumber(phoneNumberText.Text);
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(translatedNumber))
        {
            callButton.Text = "Call";
            callButton.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            callButton.Text = "Call " + translatedNumber;
            callButton.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand , can you explain a little more ?

Answer (score 0):

It adds a handler to the `Click` event. And the handler(s) will be executed in order of adding.

You can read the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx)